# ASP.NET MVC : existing website changes in Controller are not visible after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have little to no knowledge about ASP.NET but I was asked to make a few small changes for a client.

All the files are uploaded to a server. So I opened the website files via the Visual Studio FTP website method.

Any changes I do to the `.cshtml` files are visible on the website. But changes I make in the controller are not.

I've read that I need to do a build / rebuild but running this in VS Code doesn't seem to change anything.

I must be missing some steps or information.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image of file structure that is uploaded to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL2W4.png)

Comment: Do you have colleagues there you could ask on how to publish controller changes?

Comment: unfortunately no,

We don't usually do stuff in asp.net its a one time thing.
We also don't have the project files thats why i opened the website with ftp

Comment: @Ginokok1996 If you do any changes in the `Controller`, then you need to replace the `dll` file of your project in the `bin` folder via `FTP`.